# Why are these fetch methods asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Fetch is the new Promise-based API for making network requests:

```
fetch('https://www.everythingisawesome.com/')
  .then(response => console.log('status: ', response.status));
```

This makes sense to me - when we initiate a network call, we return a Promise which lets our thread carry on with other business. When the response is available, the code inside the Promise executes.

However, if I'm interested in the payload of the response, I do so via methods of the response, not properties:

- arrayBuffer()
- blob()
- formData()
- json()
- text()

These methods return promises, and I'm unclear as to why.

```
fetch('https://www.everythingisawesome.com/') //IO bound
  .then(response => response.json()); //We now have the response, so this operation is CPU bound - isn't it?
  .then(entity => console.log(entity.name));
```

Why would processing the response's payload return a promise - it's unclear to me why it should be an async operation.

Comment: _"it's unclear to me why it should be an async operation."_ Not certain what Question is? Reasons the decision was made to provide methods at `Response` object which return response in different formats using `fetch()`? Or reasons the process which returns different formats of response asynchronous?

Comment: _"it's unclear to me why it should be an async operation"_ Why should it be a synchronous operation?

Comment: Because it appears at first glance to be a CPU bound operation.

Comment: I can't follow your reasoning. Why should a CPU bound operation be synchronous?

Comment: @zeroflagL I may be leaning on my C# too much here, but in that space a CPU bound operation derives no benefit from asyncrony - the thread is eventually going to have to process it entirely. An IO-bound operation should be async such that during the time a network request is made or a file is being fetched the thread isn't left idle and can do other useful work. Outside of moving a cpu-bound code further down the event queue to manage execution flow, I can't think of a benefit of running a CPU-bound operation asyncronously in js - please let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: JavaScript runs in the same thread and event loop as the UI. CPU-intensive means blocked UI. And blocked means actually blocked, as in "cannot do anything", not just slow.

Comment: @ZuzEL What a toxic attitude. What you can do is to explain your view. That's how discussions work.

Comment: @abetteroliver I don't normally talk like this, but all the things you said just make me give up before starting any discussion. To be as concise as possible: (a) nodejs exists (b) browsers have workers where you don't block UI (c) let me decide if I want to put all my resources into CPU intensive task or not. 

Plus the fact you fall into the infinite loop in your very first attempt to answer a question, quote `"it's unclear to me why it should be an async operation" Why should it be a synchronous operation?` makes my toxic attitude absolutely justified

Comment: @ZuzEL Toxic behaviour is **never** justified. It just makes you a bad person. None of your points refute my reasoning. I did not (yet) attempt to answer the question. I wanted to understand the user's point of view first. That's why my question does not create an "infinite loop", as everyone can see from the following comments. You should understand a person's underlying assumptions so that you can craft a tailored answer. If you cannot follow my train of thought, you can ask questions. If you are unwilling to engage in a civilized manner, don't engage at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why are these fetch methods asynchronous?

The naïve answer is ["because the specification says so"](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-body-arraybuffer)

> - The `arrayBuffer()` method, when invoked, must return the result of running [consume body](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-body-consume-body) with ArrayBuffer.
> - The `blob()` method, when invoked, must return the result of running [consume body](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-body-consume-body) with Blob.
> - The `formData()` method, when invoked, must return the result of running [consume body](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-body-consume-body) with FormData.
> - The `json()` method, when invoked, must return the result of running [consume body](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-body-consume-body) with JSON.
> - The `text()` method, when invoked, must return the result of running [consume body](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-body-consume-body) with text.

Of course, that doesn't really answer the question because it leaves open the question of "Why does the spec say so?"

And this is where it gets complicated, because I'm certain of the reasoning, *but I have no evidence from an official source to prove it*. I'm going to attempt to explain the rational to the best of my understanding, but be aware that everything after here should be treated largely as outside opinion.

---

When you request data from a resource using the fetch API, you have to wait for the resource to finish downloading before you can use it. This should be reasonably obvious. JavaScript uses asynchronous APIs to handle this behavior so that the work involved doesn't block other scripts, and—more importantly—the UI.

When the resource has finished downloading, **the data might be enormous**. There's nothing that prevents you from requesting a monolithic JSON object that exceeds 50MB.

What do you think would happen if you attempted to parse 50MB of JSON synchronously? It would block other scripts, and—more importantly—the UI.

Other programmers have already solved how to handle large amounts of data in a performant manner: *Streams*. In JavaScript, streams are implemented using an asynchronous API so that they don't block, and if you read the [consume body](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-body-consume-body) details, it's clear that streams are being used to parse the data:

> Let stream be body's stream if body is non-null, or an empty ReadableStream object otherwise.

Now, it's certainly possible that the spec could have defined *two* ways of accessing the data: one synchronous API meant for smaller amounts of data, and one asynchronous API for larger amounts of data, but this would lead to confusion and duplication.

Besides [Ya Ain't Gonna Need It](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). Everything that can be expressed using synchronous code can be expressed in asynchronous code. The reverse is not true. Because of this, a single *asynchronous* API was created that could handle all use cases.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening response. I'm curious about how a stream is processed here. At some point you need to read through the stream, so if it's 50MB, it's going to have to block at that point. Is there some mechanism to ameliorate/mitigate that? Are the streams chunked and processing done with multiple async operations?

Comment: "so if it's 50MB, it's going to have to block at that point" streams only block when they're processing parts of data and only if they're part of the main JS thread (think web workers). "Are the streams chunked and processing done with multiple async operations?" pretty much exactly this. Rather than attempt to explain streams here myself, I recommend reading some [blog posts](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/05/streams-javascript-versatile-tool/) about them or otherwise researching how they work.

Answer (score 1):

Because the content is not transferred until you start reading it.  The headers come first.

Comment: Don't believe this to be true. If omit everything except the initial fetch - `fetch('http://localhost:22898/api/values');` - I still get the payload across the wire. The response headers and payload are not delivered piecemeal.

Comment: It depends on the request. If you issue a head request then you get no payload at all. Imagine you are requesting a large file. The header comes back first with details of the content. There can also be much back and forth establishing tls levels etc. Take a look at the underlying http protocol.

Comment: Hmm, sounds relevant to `OPTIONS` as well when coordinating a cross-origin request. So if the fetch operation is comprised of a HEAD and a GET, which response headers am I reading here: `.then(response => printOut(response.headers))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the implementation [here](https://github.com/github/fetch/blob/master/fetch.js) the operation of fetching `json` is CPU bound because the creation of the response, along with the body is done once the response promise is done. See the implementation of the [`json` function](https://github.com/github/fetch/blob/master/fetch.js#L245)

That being said, I think that is mostly a design concept so you can chain your promise handlers and only use a single error handler that kicks in, no matter in what stage the error happened.

Like this:

```
fetch('https://www.everythingisawesome.com/')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(function(json) {
    console.log('parsed json', json)
  })
  .catch(function(ex) {
    console.log('parsing or loading failed', ex)
  })
```

The creation of the already resolved promises is implemented with a pretty low overhead. In the end it is not required to use a promise here, but it makes for better looking code that can be written. At least in my opinion.

Comment: The code you refer to is a polyfill, so it will need to marry up with the native implementation. As for a design consideration, I'm unsure what value multiple promise handlers provides us. It would be less readable, not more, to wrap each statement in its own Promise, so there must be some technical reason.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the implementation of fetch, it seems that promises are used for a few reasons. For starters, `json()` relies on a `FileReader` to convert the response blob into text. `FileReaders` can't be used until the `onload` callback, so that's where the promise chain starts.

```
function fileReaderReady(reader) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    reader.onload = function() {
      resolve(reader.result)
    }
    reader.onerror = function() {
      reject(reader.error)
    }
  })
}
```

From there, additional promises are used to encapsulate particular errors that might occur and propagating them up to the caller. For example, there are errors that can occur if the body has already be read once before, if the blob doesn't convert to text, and if the text doesn't convert to JSON. Promises are convenient here because any of these various errors will simply end up in the catch block of the caller.

So in conclusion, a promised based api is used for reading fetch responses because:
1. They rely on a `FileReader` which has to initialize itself asynchronously.
2. fetch would like to propagate a wide variety of errors that may occur in reading the body. Promises allow a uniform way to do this.

Comment: _"After reading through the implementation of fetch"_ You haven't. The code in your answer is JavaScript and a Polyfill at best. That aside, an implementation doesn't drive the interface - It's the other way around.

Comment: @zeroflagL that code snippet was taken from fetch.js on the master branch of the main repo.

Comment: @zeroflagL Sorry, I didn't realize the fetch repo was actually a polyfill for something native. I'll remove my answer but I suspect that reason for the native implementation being promised are similar. If the implementation is async and error-prone, promises are a natural way to express that in the interface.

Comment: Sure, the specification is similar: A reader that returns a promise.